# Let's Encrypt Nginx-plugin installation and usage

Tags: nginx, ssl, lets-encrypt

Let's Encrypt just released their open beta, which is great.

I'm using Nginx as a webserver and I know that Let's Encrypt so far only supports Nginx via plugin.

**Now the problem is** this:
*I'm not quite sure how I should install and use that plugin.*

I've been trying to run it with this command, referred from [their documentation](https://letsencrypt.org/howitworks/) :

```
./letsencrypt-auto certonly --standalone -d example.com -d www.example.com
```

**And changed --standalone to nginx ofc**

No matter how I've tried, the result answer is always the same:

```
$ The requested nginx plugin does not appear to be installed
```

Any ideas how to make nginx and Let's Encrypt work together?

Cheers!

Comment: As the README told you, the plugin doesn't work and is disabled.

Comment: See these instructions for nginx: https://www.wjd.io/lets-encrypt-beta (I would have added this as answer, but as everything gets downvoted here, I refrain from doing so)

Comment: @simon Answeres rarely get downvoted as they cost people UIPs. The link you provide is currently 503.

Comment: "The link you provide is currently 503" -- nicely demonstrating why we don't like link-only answers...

Comment: Can't you just use 'webroot' or 'manual' for nginx?  Or one of the other ACME clients?

Comment: "the plugin doesn't work and is disabled" — It doesn't say that. It says that it's "very experimental", which is completely different.

Comment: Here's the solution that gave my homeserver that green lock aka SSL connection. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-14-04 Cheers!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Time passes and it seems that now

```
letsencrypt-auto certonly --standalone
```

now works as expected

---

The README.rst supplied as part of the git repo you reference in your question has this to say

> - nginx/0.8.48+ (highly experimental, not included in letsencrypt-auto)

Erm ... that's it.

<sub>Iain's reading manuals as a service (RMAAS) at your erm ... service</sub>

Comment: Yeah...erm...to me it seems to say that nginx is not supported for lets encrypt auto. Also, "highly experimental" != not working. Thanks anyway.

Comment: We're not mind readers, this is the answer to the question you asked.

Comment: @Shamppi is right. "Highly experimental" is not the same as "doesn't work". No need to be obnoxious.

Answer (score 4):

This is how I installed the nginx plugin on a CentOS 6 machine after installing python 2.7.

```
# ~/.local/share/letsencrypt/bin/pip install -U letsencrypt-nginx
# ./letsencrypt-auto plugins  | grep '^*'
* apache
* nginx
* standalone
* webroot
#
```

Comment: Thanks @vikas027, the exact same command works on Ubuntu 14.04 x64

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to create let'sencrypt certificate using certbot for my sub-domain and had following issue. 
**Command :**

> ubuntu@localhost:~$ certbot --nginx -d my_subdomain.website.com

**Issue :**

> The requested nginx plugin does not appear to be installed

**Solution:**

> ubuntu@localhost:~$ sudo apt-get install python-certbot-nginx

Comment: This worked for me. For the records, I have downloaded certbot after following this - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SSL-on-amazon-linux-2.html#letsencrypt